# Akka Streams Error Handling. How to know which row failed?

Tags: scala, akka-stream

I read this article on akka streams error handling

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-error.html

and wrote this code.

```
val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case _: Exception => Supervision.Restart
  case _ => Supervision.Stop
}

implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()
implicit val actorMaterializer = ActorMaterializer(ActorMaterializerSettings(actorSystem).withSupervisionStrategy(decider))

val source = Source(1 to 10)
 val flow = Flow[Int].map{x => if (x != 9) 2 * x else throw new Exception("9!")}
 val sink : Sink[Int, Future[Done]] = Sink.foreach[Int](x => println(x))
 val graph = RunnableGraph.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create(sink){implicit builder => s =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._
  source ~> flow ~> s.in
  ClosedShape
})
val future = graph.run()
future.onComplete{ _ =>
  actorSystem.terminate()
}
Await.result(actorSystem.whenTerminated, Duration.Inf)
```

This works very well .... except that I need to scan the output to see which row did not get processed. Is there a way for me to print/log the row which failed? [Without putting explicit try/catch blocks in each and every flow that I write?]

So for example If I was using actors (as opposed to streams) I could have written a life cycle event of an actor and I could have logged when an actor restarted along with the message which was being processed at the time of restart.

but here I am not using actors explicitly (although they are used internally). Are there life cycle events for a Flow / Source / Sink?

Comment: Could you fork the stream and push the bad ones to a different "bad" queue where they just get logged out (or whatever you want to do with them) ?

Comment: So .. In order to fork the stream, you will still have to catch all exceptions, and in the catch block route to a different flow... won't that be very tedious? is there a simple was to fork the stream with failed messages?

Comment: Oh I didn't understand your example, I thought your conditional statement indicated that you knew the case to look out for in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a small modification to your code:

```
  val decider: Supervision.Decider = {
  case e: Exception =>
    println("Exception handled, recovering stream:" + e.getMessage)
    Supervision.Restart
  case _ => Supervision.Stop
}
```

If you pass meaningful messages to your exceptions in the stream, the line for example, you can print them in the supervision decider.

I used `println` to give a quick and short answer, but strongly recommend to use 
some logging libraries such as `scala-logging`